# Missing 1 Required Positional Argument: part5() Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am pretty much a beginner at Python and for my assignment I am creating a text based game and I want to make an item system. However, there is an error in part7a that says TypeError: part7a() missing 1 required positional argument: 'part5'.

I am unsure why the item_count is not carrying over and if someone could provide any kind of assisstance it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
    def part5():
    print("As you venture across the path, you reach a crossroads...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("You stop at the crossroads as you are met with 3 different paths...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Something shiny on the floor catches your eye...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("You look down and it appears to be an old sword with a blue gem in its core...")
    answer = ""
    while answer.lower().strip() != "yes" and answer.lower().strip() != "no":
        answer = input("Take the sword? (yes/no): ")

        if answer.lower().strip() == "yes":
            item_count = 0
            item_count = item_count + 1
            time.sleep(1)
            print("- Item added to your backpack -")
            time.sleep(2)
            print("You pick up the sword, now it's time to make your decision.")
            time.sleep(2)
            part6()
        elif answer.lower().strip() == "no":
            time.sleep(2)
            print("You think nothing of the sword and carry on to make your decision.")
            time.sleep(2)
            part6()

    return


def part6():
    answer = ""
    while answer != "1" and answer != "2" and answer != "3":
        answer = input("What path will you choose? (1/2/3): ")

    battleAnswer = "2"

    if answer == battleAnswer:
        time.sleep(2)
        print("You head down path", answer+"...")
        part7a()
    else:
        time.sleep(2)
        print("You head down path", answer+"...")
        part7b()

    return



def part7a(part5):
        time.sleep(2)
        print("After travelling for a while you find the path becoming darker...")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("And darker...")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Until...")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("A tall dark monster appears before you...")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Lets hope you know what you're doing!!")
        time.sleep(1)
        answer = ""
        while answer.lower.strip() != "yes" and answer.lower().strip() != "no":
            answer = input("Fight the monster? (yes/no): ")

            if answer == "yes" and item_count == 1:
                time.sleep(2)
                print("- Sword equipped from backpack -")
                time.sleep(2)
                print("You firmly grasp the sword in your hands...")
                time.sleep(2)
                print("It fills you with determination...")
                time.sleep(2)
                print("The monster charges towards you...")
                time.sleep(2)
                print("You run up with your sword, challenging the monster...")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("The monster accepts your challenge and begins running towards you...")
                time.sleep(2)
                print("Stomp, stomp, STOMP!!")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("SLICEEEEEEEE!")
                time.sleep(2)
                print("With a brave slash of your sword you slice through the monster...")
                time.sleep(2)
                print("You face monster that had been cut in two...")
                time.sleep(2)
                print("It looks you in the eye as it slowly fades away into dust.")
                time.sleep(3)
                part8()
            else:
                time.sleep(2)
                print("In a brave effort you attempt to sprint around the monster...")
                time.sleep(2)
                print("It looks down at you and stomps on you as if you are an ant.")
                time.sleep(2)
                restart()


def part7b():
    print('hello')
```

Comment: You declared `def part7a(part5)`, but call it as `part7a()`. You need to fill the parameter, or remove it as you are not using it.